# Erro de php --> mysql

Tags: php

```
$nome=$_POST['nome'];

$sobrenome=$_POST['sobrenome'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$senha=$_POST['senha'];

$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, sobrenome, email, senha)
VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");
```

O erro que está dando: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/u158302715/public_html/bemvindo.php on line 40`

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro parâmetro tem que se a conexão do MySQL que você está abrindo pelo `mysqli_connect()`. Para você usar somente a query você teria que usar o modo estático da função com `mysqli::query()`.

Dá uma olhada na documentação dessa função no php.net: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php

Agora veja o exemplo de código aqui no W3Schools:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Note a linha:
`$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");`

E agora veja que `$con` é passado como parâmetro:
`mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");`

Comment: obrigado, mas no caso a conexão já está estabelecida, mas quando chega no mysqli_query dá este erro

Comment: Porque você não está passando o parâmetro para a função que você chamou aqui: `mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, sobrenome, email, senha)
VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");` teria que ser algo do tipo `mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, sobrenome, email, senha)
VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");`

Answer (score 0):

e simples no seu código esta assim `$sql = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, sobrenome, email, senha) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");` troque por isso

`$sql = mysqli_query($variavel de conexao, "INSERT INTO usuarios (nome, sobrenome, email, senha) VALUES ('$nome', '$sobrenome', '$email', '$senha')");`

você esta usando `mysqli` e a forma da escrita esta como era escrito antes no `mysql`, portanto sempre que você tiver uma `query` do `mysqli` sempre terá que passar a `conexao` nela`